# Multiply all items of vector by single item of another vector

Tags: r, vector

The question is very simple. How to multiply every element of vector A by single element of vector B.

Here is the example:

```
> a
[1] 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5

> b
[1] 250  252  252
```

The final result should return one object which looks similar to:

```
1   1250 1250 1250 1250 1250 1250 1250 1250
2   1260 1260 1260 1260 1260 1260 1260 1260
3   1260 1260 1260 1260 1260 1260 1260 1260
```

I've spent some time by trying do this by function `for` but I couldn't get proper result.

Some examples how to achieve that will be perfect answer.

Thanks.

Comment: This looks like you're going for a matrix multiplication (row vector times a column vector), and it looks like R supports matrix multiplication: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/matmult.html

Comment: `outer(b,a)` or `b %o% a`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `tcrossprod`

```
> tcrossprod(b,a)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,] 1250 1250 1250 1250 1250 1250 1250 1250
[2,] 1260 1260 1260 1260 1260 1260 1260 1260
[3,] 1260 1260 1260 1260 1260 1260 1260 1260
```

You can also use `%*%` as in: `b %*% t(a)`